# How to systematically fill in values in a tuple dictionary set

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple dict set in python stored like {(ID, type): value}. I need to systematically add entries for every ID, type combination and then add 0 as the value. Here's an example of the data:

```
{(1,2): 5, (2,1): 7, (3,2): 15, (4,3): 10}
```

For this example IDs range from 1-4 and types from 1-3. The end product I need is:

```
{(1,1):0, (1,2):5, (1,3): 0, (2,1):7, (2,2):0, (2,3):0, (3,1):0, (3,2):15, (3,3):0, (4,1):0, (4,2):0, (4,3):10}
```

How would you go about efficiently achieving that end product?  Thank you

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `data.get((id_, type), 0)`, to get a default 0 in cases where no value has been set

Comment: What's the problem with your own code?

Comment: Unless you need to iterate over the whole (filled up) dictionary at some point, you may want to look in to defaultdict from the collections module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) in a loop over the [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of the keys:

```
from itertools import product

d = {(1,2): 5, (2,1): 7, (3,2): 15, (4,3): 10}

for t in product(*map(set, zip(*d.keys()))):
    d.setdefault(t, 0)
```

Note that if you know the ranges, you can simplify to:

```
for t in product([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]):
    d.setdefault(t, 0)
```

Output:

```
{(1, 2): 5,
 (2, 1): 7,
 (3, 2): 15,
 (4, 3): 10,
 (1, 1): 0,
 (1, 3): 0,
 (2, 2): 0,
 (2, 3): 0,
 (3, 1): 0,
 (3, 3): 0,
 (4, 2): 0,
 (4, 1): 0}
```

##### timing

on 1M items:

```
430 ms ± 22.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```